# Accessing Planet Basic Imagery

Tags: planet

I have recently begun accessing Planet data through the Planet Explorer interface.  I am most interested in the Planet Basic imagery.  These are the images that have not yet been orthorectified.  For nearly all scenes I see the Analytic and Visual products, but not the Basic.  Is there something I need to do to make this option available?

Comment: Scott, could you add detail on specific items that are missing basic assets?  Ideally a complete url to the item.

Comment: Hi Frank,  An example item would be 20160902_202028_0e14.  I'm not sure how to get the link, but hopefully that gives you enough to start.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planet's regular accounts only have access to the visual and analytic imagery options. The basic imagery formats are reserved for more advanced users. Your best best is to contact [Planet support](https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with a description of what you are trying to do and ask for access to basic with your account.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  I have emailed Planet support and asked them if, perhaps, I do not have access.

Comment: Indeed, this was the issue.  The awesome folks at Planet support updated my account settings and it seems to be working great now.